# problemas con parámetros en métodos de una clase en java

Tags: java, método

tengo un problema al momento de realizar las acciones de busqueda(si existe el valor en mi arreglo) el profesor no explico lo demas asi que tengo esa duda el programa ya al llamar `tra.AltaOrdenado(Tra, arrtra);` `tra` no tiene ningún valor, y en si no busca nada.

aqui dejo mi codigo:

```
package empleo;
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Empleo {
public static tra arrtra[] = new tra[5];
public static tra Tra = new tra();


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in);

        int menu = 0;
         do{
        do{
        System.out.println("_____________________________"
                + "\nSISTEMA REGISTRO DE TRABAJADORES");

        System.out.println("\nElija una opción"
                       + "\n[1.-]ALTA A NUEVO TRABAJADOR           "
                       + "\n[2.-]BAJA A TRABAJADOR         "
                       + "\n[3.-]MODIFICAR A TRABAJADOR     "
                       + "\n[4.-]CONSULTAR A TODOS LOS TRABAJADORES"
                       + "\n[5.-]CONSULTAR A UN TRABAJADOR  "
                       + "\n[6.-]SALIR          ");


        menu = opcion.nextInt();

        switch(menu){
            case 1:
            {

              tra.AltaOrdenado(Tra, arrtra);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
               tra.Baja(Tra, arrtra);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
               tra.Modificar(Tra, arrtra);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
               tra.ConsultaTodos(arrtra);
                break;
            }
            case 5:
            {

                break;
            }
            case 6:
            {
               System.out.println("Saliendo.."); 
            }
            default:
            {
                    System.out.println("OPCIÓN INVALIDA\n");


            }
        }
        }while(menu < 1 && menu > 6);
        }while(menu != 6);
    }

}
```

---

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package empleo;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Pedro
 */
public class tra {

    public String Nombre;
    public String Cargo;
    public int Edad;
    public int ID;

    public tra(String Nombre,String Cargo,int edad,int ID)
    {
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Cargo = Cargo;
        this.Edad = edad;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    public tra(String Nombre,String Cargo,int edad)
    {
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Cargo = Cargo;
        this.Edad = edad;
        this.ID = 0;
    }

    public tra(String Nombre,String Cargo)
    {
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Cargo = Cargo;
        this.Edad = 0;
        this.ID = 0;
    }

    public tra(String Nombre)
    {
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Cargo = "";
        this.Edad = 0;
        this.ID = 0;
    }

    public tra()
    {
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Cargo = "";
        this.Edad = 0;
        this.ID = 0;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return Cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String Cargo) {
        this.Cargo = Cargo;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return Edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int Edad) {
        this.Edad = Edad;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return    "\n" 
                + "\nNombre=" + Nombre
                + "\nCargo=" + Cargo 
                + "\nEdad=" + Edad 
                + "\nID=" + ID;
    }

    public void IngresarDatos(){
        Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Nombre = "";
        String Cargo = "";
        int Edad = 0;
        int ID = 0;

        System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del nuevo trabajador:"
                + "\nNombre:");
        Nombre = dato.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Cargo:");
        Cargo = dato.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Edad:");
        Edad = dato.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Identificador(ID):");
        ID = dato.nextInt();

        this.setNombre(Nombre);
        this.setCargo(Cargo);
        this.setEdad(Edad);
        this.setID(ID);
    }
        public static int Contador = 0;

    public static tra unoleer(){
        tra Nuevo = new tra();
        Nuevo.IngresarDatos();
        return Nuevo;
    }
    public static int Buscar(tra elemento, tra Arreglo[]) {

        int i = 0;

        int posicion = 0;
        if(Contador == 0)
        {
//            System.out.println("La lista està vacia");
            return -2;
        }
        else
        {
         while (i < Contador && elemento.ID > Arreglo[i].ID) {
            i++;
         }
         /*
        Si i == contador, no se encontró el elemento
        Por lo tanto el elemento no existe en la lista.
        Entonces i, tendrà el valor de la posición final donde se insertarà
        el nuevo elemento, entonces pos debe contener esa posición.
        */
         if (i >= Contador || elemento.ID< Arreglo[i].ID) {
            posicion = i;
         } 
         else 
         {
            /*Si i es menor que Contador, entonces, el elemento ya existe
             Entonces, pos contendrà -1
            */
            if (i < Contador) {
                posicion = -1;
            }
         }

        return posicion;
        }

    }
    //*********************************************************************
    public static void AltaOrdenado(tra elemento,tra []lista)
    {
     int indice = 0;
    if(Contador < lista.length) 
     {
       indice = Buscar(elemento, lista);
         if (indice == -2) {
             System.out.println("La lista está vacia\n");
         }

       elemento = unoleer();

       indice = Buscar(elemento, lista);

//       
       if(indice == -1)
       {
           System.out.println("el registro ya está en la lista\n");
       }
       else 
       {
        if(indice == -2) //Lista vacia, se inserta en la posiciòn 0
        {
         lista[0] = elemento;
         System.out.println("Inserción exitosa.\n");
         Contador++;
        }
        else
        {
         for(int i = Contador;i > indice;i--)
         {
            lista[i] = lista[i-1];

         }
         lista[indice] = elemento;
         System.out.println("Inserción exitosa.\n");
         Contador++;
        }
       }

     }
   else System.out.println("No se puede insertar. La lista està llena\n");
    }
    //******************************************************************
     public static void BajaOrdenado(tra elemento, tra arreglo[]){
   int i = 0;
   if(Contador <= 0)
   {
       System.out.println("La lista està vacia\n");
   }
   else
   {
    int posicion = BuscarActualizar(elemento,arreglo);
    if(posicion == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("El elemento no està en la lista\n");
    }
    else
    {
     arreglo[posicion] = null;
     Contador --;
     for(i = posicion; i < Contador; i++)
     {
      arreglo[i] = arreglo[i+1];   
     }
     arreglo[i] = null;
    }
   }
   }
     //***************************************************************
    public static int BuscarActualizar(tra elemento, tra arreglo[]) {
        int i = 0;

        int pos = 0;
        if(Contador == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("La lista està vacia\n");
            return -2;
        }
        else
        {
         while (i < Contador && elemento.ID > arreglo[i].ID) {
            i++;
         }
         /*
        regresar la posicion del elemento a eleiminar
         regresar 0, si no existe
         regresar -2, si la lista esta vacia 
        */
         if (i >= Contador || elemento.ID < arreglo[i].ID) {
            pos = -1;
         } 
         else 
         {
            /*Si i es menor que Contador, entonces, el elemento ya existe
             Entonces, pos contendrà -1
            */
            if (i < Contador) {
                pos = i;
            }
         }

        return pos;
        }

    }
   //**********************************************************
    public static <T> void ConsultaTodos ( T [] Arreglo)
    {
     T elemento; 
        System.out.println("\nELEMENTOS REGISTRADOS:" + Contador + "{");
        for(int i = 0; i < Arreglo.length; i++){
            elemento = Arreglo[i];
            if (Arreglo[i] != null) {
                System.out.printf("%s ", elemento);
            }


        }
        System.out.println("\n}\n");
    }
 //*************************************************************
    public static  void ConsultaUno(tra arrtra[]){
           Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
           int i = 0;
           int o = 0;
           Object elemento;

           System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de registro del Reo"
                   + "\nque desea consultar");
           i = dato.nextInt();

           for (int j = 0; j < arrtra.length; j++) {
               if( arrtra[j] != null){
               if (i == arrtra[j].ID) {
                   elemento = arrtra[j];
                   System.out.println(elemento);
                   o = 1;
               }
             }
           }
           if ( o != 1) {
               System.out.println("No se encontró el registro\n");
           }

       }
    //**********************************************************
    public static void ModificarOrdenado(tra elemento, tra lista[]){
       int indice = 0;
       if(Contador < lista.length) 
       {
       indice = Buscar(elemento, lista);

       if(indice == -1)
       {
           System.out.println("el registro ya está en la lista\n");
       }
       else 
       {
        if(indice == -2) //Lista vacia, se inserta en la posiciòn 0
        {
         lista[0] = elemento;

         Contador++;
        }
        else
        {
         for(int i = Contador;i > indice;i--)
         {
            lista[i] = lista[i-1];

         }
         lista[indice] = elemento;

         Contador++;
        }
       }

     }
   else System.out.println("No se puede insertar. La lista està llena\n");
     }
    //**********************************************************
    public static void Modificar(tra elemento, tra arrtra[]){
           Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
           int i = 0;
           int o = 0;
           int u = 0;


           tra a = new tra();

           System.out.println("Ingrese un registro a modificar");
           i = dato.nextInt();

           for (int j = 0; j < arrtra.length; j++) {
               if (arrtra[j] != null) {
                   if (i == arrtra[j].ID) {
                       o = 1;
                       a.IngresarDatos();
                       elemento = arrtra[j];
                       BajaOrdenado(elemento, arrtra);
                       u = Contador;
                       ModificarOrdenado(a, arrtra);
                       if (u != Contador) {
                           System.out.println("Modificación exitosa");
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           if (u == Contador) {
               ModificarOrdenado(elemento, arrtra);

           }
           if (o != 1) {
               System.out.println("no se encontró el registro\n");
           }
       }
    //********************************************************
    public static void Baja(tra reo, tra arrtra[]){
            if (arrtra[0] != null) {
               Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
           int i = 0;
           int o = 0;
           tra elemento;
           System.out.println("Ingrese el registro a eliminar");
           i = dato.nextInt();

           for (int j = 0; j < arrtra.length; j++) {
               if( arrtra[j] != null){
               if (i == arrtra[j].ID) {
                   elemento = arrtra[j];
                   o = 1;
                   BajaOrdenado(elemento, arrtra);
               }
             }
           }
           if (o != 1) {
               System.out.println("No se encontró el registro\n");
           } 
            }else{
                System.out.println("La lista está vacía\n");
            }



       }

}
```

Comment: Para tener claro en lo que quieres ayuda, es en la parte de buscar un empleado dentro de las posiciones del arreglo o me equivoco?

Comment: Si, se supone que utilizamos`public static tra Tra = new tra();`
Y en el case 1 `tra.AltaOrdenado(Tra, arrtra);` pero `Tra` no tiene nada, y no entiendo.

Comment: supongo que debes de rellenar primero `Tra` y luego poder utilizar las opciones, antes de utilizarlas le debes de pedir al usuario los datos para llenar tra, según medio entiendo....

Answer (score 0):

Crea un POJO de Empleado y utiliza la clase ArrayList te va a hacer más fácil buscar los objetos. Mírate esto  https://jarroba.com/arraylist-en-java-ejemplos/

```
 public class Empleado{
     private String nombre
     private Sttring apellido
     ....
 }

 ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados  = new ArrayList<>();
```

Otra cosas las clases empiezan con mayúscula

`public class Tra {`